# Custom Pagination based on Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, pagination, genesis-theme-framework

I'm using the Genesis Framework and want to have different Pagination for each Custom Post Type (I have two, work and employees).  I also have standards posts.

The custom pagination is working for Employees and Work but not for standard posts, the pagination for Employees is showing.  Here are the example pages:

Employees:

http://dr.betaforming.com/studio/people/dawn-ter-horst-senior-interior-designer-business-development/

Work:

http://dr.betaforming.com/work/bradley-montgomery/

Standard Posts:

http://dr.betaforming.com/recognition/publicity/2015-monumental-achievement-award-interior-design/

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'dr_prev_next_post_nav' );
function dr_prev_next_post_nav() {

    genesis_markup( array(
        'html5'   => '<div %s>',
        'xhtml'   => '<div class="navigation">',
        'context' => 'adjacent-entry-pagination',
    ) );

    if ( is_singular( array( 'employees', 'post' ) ) ) {
        echo '<div class="pagination-previous one-half first alignleft">';
        previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous Employee' );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="pagination-next one-half alignright">';
        next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Employee' );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

    } elseif ( is_singular( array( 'work', 'post' ) ) ) {

        echo '<div class="pagination-previous one-third first alignleft">';
        if (strlen(get_previous_post()->post_title) > 0) { 
            previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous Project', TRUE, '', 'work-type' );
        } else {
            echo '&nbsp';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="one-third content-centered">';
        echo '<button id="toggle-content" class="project-toggle">Project Description</button>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="pagination-next one-third alignright">';

        if (strlen(get_next_post()->post_title) > 0) {
            next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Project', TRUE, '', 'work-type' );
        } else {
            echo '&nbsp';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

    } else { 

        echo '<div class="pagination-previous one-half first alignleft">';
        previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous Publicity Article' );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="pagination-next one-half alignright">';
        next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Publicity Article' );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after reviewing the code reference for is_singular some more.

Here is the final code:

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'dr_prev_next_post_nav' );
function dr_prev_next_post_nav() {

    genesis_markup( array(
        'html5'   => '<div %s>',
        'xhtml'   => '<div class="navigation">',
        'context' => 'adjacent-entry-pagination',
    ) );

    if ( is_singular( array( 'employees' ) ) ) {
        echo '<div class="pagination-previous one-half first alignleft">';
        previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous Employee' );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="pagination-next one-half alignright">';
        next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Employee' );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

    } elseif ( is_singular( array( 'work' ) ) ) {

        echo '<div class="pagination-previous one-third first alignleft">';
        if (strlen(get_previous_post()->post_title) > 0) { 
            previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous Project', TRUE, '', 'work-type' );
        } else {
            echo '&nbsp';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="one-third content-centered">';
        echo '<button id="toggle-content" class="project-toggle">Project Description</button>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="pagination-next one-third alignright">';

        if (strlen(get_next_post()->post_title) > 0) {
            next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Project', TRUE, '', 'work-type' );
        } else {
            echo '&nbsp';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

    } elseif ( is_singular( 'post' )) { 

        echo '<div class="pagination-previous one-half first alignleft">';
        previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous Publicity Article' );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="pagination-next one-half alignright">';
        next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Publicity Article' );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

    }
}
```